# The EBS direct APIs AmazonEBSClient.GetSnapshotBlockAsync is very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

I use EBS direct APIs to access the contents of an EBS snapshot, when I called the .NET API AmazonEBSClient.GetSnapshotBlockAsync to get the data in block, the response was very slow, almost 5 minutes after I called the GetSnapshotBlockAsync, there was no exceptions and throttling errors during the call. The size of the snapshot is a little big, which is at TB level, I was wondering why the API is so slow?

any method to speed up the API response or do I use the API in a wrong way?

Thanks，